# Ardour .desktop file not executing

Tags: .desktop, ardour

I have configured and built the source code for Ardour 5.4 successfully, and have been able to run it from the terminal after exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH to ~/.bashrc (for me, the path was /usr/local/lib/ardour5, if that helps anybody out there) and adding ARDOUR_DATA_PATH (usr/local/share/ardour5), ARDOUR_CONFIG_PATH (usr/local/etc/ardour5), and ARDOUR_DLL_PATH (usr/local/lib/ardour5) to /etc/environment.

However, I want to be able to run the program from the Ubuntu Dash, and building Ardour did not create a desktop file. I found a file called "ardour.desktop.in" in the gtk2_folder of Ardour's directory tree after building it, and copied and pasted its contents as a new text file called "ardour.desktop" in /usr/share/applications. Here is the contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Ardour
Comment=Ardour Digital Audio Workstation
Exec=/usr/local/lib/ardour5/ardour-5.4.0
Icon=/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-yakkety-universe/64x64/ardour_ardour.png
Terminal=false
MimeType=application/x-ardour;
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Audio;AudioEditing;X-Recorders;X-Multitrack;X-Jack;
```

I then set executable permissions using "chmod 755 ardour.desktop" and tried to run it, but nothing happened. I tried running the desktop file from the terminal and got these results:

```
./ardour.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
./ardour.desktop: line 4: Digital: command not found
./ardour.desktop: line 10: Audio: command not found
./ardour.desktop: line 10: AudioEditing: command not found
./ardour.desktop: line 10: X-Recorders: command not found
./ardour.desktop: line 10: X-Multitrack: command not found
./ardour.desktop: line 10: X-Jack: command not found
```

I've finally resorted to asking for help here, as I am completely stumped. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Install and use "menulibre" or "alacarte"  to create Unity launchers.  you get errors  is because you cannot run a launcher as a bash or executable  file .

Comment: I was linking the Exec command to the wrong file. The correct file is a shell script that runs Ardour in the build/gtk2_folder Ardour's directory tree called "Ardour5". This allows me to successfully run Ardour from the launcher without needing the terminal. I thought it was something obvious!